# Excel VBA SQL UNION SUM with GROUP BY on Tables with Different Column Names

Tags: sql, excel, vba, group-by, union-all

I have two tables, with different column names, as follows:

Table Orders:
**Due Date, Pay, Exchange Rate**

Table Invoices:
**Date, Subtotal, Exchange Rate**

I'd like the following resulting table:
**Year, Month, Total**

Where the two tables are UNIONED ALL on date + month and Total is the SUM of all rows in the two tables.

My pseudo-SQL looks like this:

```
SELECT YearID, MonthID, SUM(Amount) FROM (

  SELECT YEAR(ORDREC.[Due Date]) as YearID, MONTH(ORDREC.[Due Date]) as MonthID, SUM(ORDREC.[Pay] * ORDREC.[Exchange Rate]) as Amount
  FROM orders-table AS ORDREC
  WHERE ...

UNION ALL

  SELECT YEAR(INV.[Date]) as YearID, MONTH(INV.[Date]) as MonthID, SUM(INV.[Subtotal] * INV.[Exchange Rate]) as Amount
  FROM invoices-table AS INV
  WHERE ...

) x GROUP BY YearID, MonthID
```

I'm failing on the GROUP BY, for using ALIASES (error saying not using YEAR(ORDREC.[Due Date]) in an aggregate function), but I must use aliases as the column names are DIFFERENT in the two tables. Any suggestions on how to achieve this in a single SQL query?

Excel 2016 on Windows 10
Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;

Comment: Your second table will not need the alias field names - a union query picks all field names from the first table.  That wouldn't cause the error - just sayin'. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use *aggregate function* you need to add non-aggregate columns in `GROUP BY` clause.

You use `SUM` aggregate function in your `UNION ALL` query,  need to add non-aggregate columns in `GROUP BY` clause in the two query.

```
SELECT YearID, MonthID, SUM(Amount) FROM (

  SELECT YEAR(ORDREC.[Due Date]) as YearID, MONTH(ORDREC.[Due Date]) as MonthID, SUM(ORDREC.[Pay] * ORDREC.[Exchange Rate]) as Amount
  FROM orders-table AS ORDREC
  WHERE ...
  GROUP BY YEAR(ORDREC.[Due Date]),MONTH(ORDREC.[Due Date])
  UNION ALL

  SELECT YEAR(INV.[Date]) as YearID, MONTH(INV.[Date]) as MonthID, SUM(INV.[Subtotal] * INV.[Exchange Rate]) as Amount
  FROM invoices-table AS INV
  WHERE ...
  GROUP BY YEAR(INV.[Date]),MONTH(INV.[Date])

) x GROUP BY YearID, MonthID
```

if I understand correctly, you can use this then do `SUM` *aggregate function*, I think the error will disappear.

```
SELECT YearID, MonthID, SUM(Amount) FROM (
  SELECT YEAR(ORDREC.[Due Date]) as YearID, MONTH(ORDREC.[Due Date]) as MonthID, (ORDREC.[Pay] * ORDREC.[Exchange Rate]) as Amount
  FROM orders-table AS ORDREC
  WHERE ...
  UNION ALL
  SELECT YEAR(INV.[Date]) as YearID, MONTH(INV.[Date]) as MonthID, (INV.[Subtotal] * INV.[Exchange Rate]) as Amount
  FROM invoices-table AS INV
  WHERE ...

) x GROUP BY YearID, MonthID
```